# application.xml for Jboss 6

Tags: maven, jboss6.x, maven-ear-plugin, application.xml

Can we package ear for jboss 6 ? What will be application.xml uri ??

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  /application_5.xsd">

<display-name>my-ear</display-name>
<module>
    <ejb>my-ejb</ejb>
</module>
```

I have tried changing version for version=6 but it is saying file not found.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_6_0.dtd
```

Does any one have face such problem with jboss 6 while deploying ear ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it using maven ear plugin and removing manually created application.xml.

Here is my ear pom it might be helpful for other

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.surajchhetry.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-ear</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<name>test-ear</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>test-ear</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-ejb</artifactId>                           
                        <bundleFileName>test-ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <jarModule>
                       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>                            
                        <bundleFileName>test-api.jar</bundleFileName>                           
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>

    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 5.0 one - it should be available locally in $JBOSS/docs/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd

The xml above is something different though and goverened by some other schema documents - this does not match the error you show.

You need to change the file `jboss-app.xml` to use a doctype of

```
DOCTYPE jboss-app
PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Java EE Application 5.0//EN"
"http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is my application.xml                                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>my-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>my-ejb</ejb>
  </module>
</application>

Comment: and error iam getting  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_6_0.dtd

Comment: first: you are allowed to edit your original question, instead of adding comments. Then this error message you are posting says it can not find **jboss-app**_6_0 - there is none, this has nothing to do with **application.xml**. Post your jboss-app.xml file

Comment: <!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 1.5//EN"
"http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_6_0.dtd">
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>
    blb-ear:archive=blb-ear.ear
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>